# laravel load invidual blade component into main component along with script of the component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have one file which contain 3 component. for example

```
<div1></div1>
<div2></div2>
<div3></div3>
@section('script')
<script>
/**
  contains div1,div2,div3 dependent script
**/
</script>
```

Now i have kept separate blade.php for `div` element

for example,

**div1.blade.php**

```
<div1>
</div1>
@section('script')
<script>
// this contain all the script related to div1 like ajax call and other things
</script>
```

**div2.blade.php**

```
<div2>
</div2>
@section('script')
<script>
// this contain all the script related to div2 like ajax call and other things
</script>
```

**div3.blade.php**

```
<div3>
</div3>
@section('script')
<script>
// this contain all the script related to div3 like ajax call and other things
</script>
```

Now i have included all this blade component into main component

**main.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
   
   @include('div1.blade')
   @include('div2.blade')
   @include('div3.blade')

@endsection

@section('script')
//common script
@endsection
```

These all i have done and not getting how to load individual component script in **main.blade.php**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the below method to achieve your goal.

// main.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    @yield('style')
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
   @yield('content')


    @yield('script')
  </body>
</html>
```

Now Extend the above main.blade.php file in your other files.

// other.blade.php

```
@extend('main')

@section('style')
//your all style files 
@endsection

@section('content')
//your page content 
@endsection

@section('script')
//your all scripts files
@endsection
```

I hope it helps.